# Connecting to local database

Tags: c#

I am trying to create to a local database via a mdf file, like so:

```
scon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\articles.mdf; Integrated Security=True");
scon.Open();
scmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO articles(url) VALUES(@url)");
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", "http://google.com");
scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

MY mdf file is in the root folder, and in the debug folder too. When I run the following code I get an error saying the following:

[image]

I can't use the full connection path because it's a long url with spaces, here is my file structure:

[image]

My database exists:

[image]

How can I fix this so I can connect to my database?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the folders by removing any spaces and other non alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the connection object to the SqlCommand constructor

```
scmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO articles(url) VALUES(@url)", scon);
```

The connectionstring is fine, the error message informs you that it is not possible to execute a command if the database is not known. The SqlConnection contains this information and you need to pass it to your command.
Another possibility is through the

```
scmd.Connection = scon;
```

but, personally, I prefer to pass that info in the constructor.

**Final but really important note**:
SqlConnection and SqlCommand are disposable objects. You should always dispose these kind of objects. The using statement is the correct method

```
using(scon = new SqlConnection(....))
using(scmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO articles(url) VALUES(@url)",scon))
{
   scon.Open();
   scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", "http://google.com");
   scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: `SqlCommand` does not really need to be disposed. The only reason it is disposeable is it inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component`. Neither `SqlCommand` nor `DbCommand` do anything during disposing. The only thing that happens when you dispose of a command is [you cause the `.Disposed` event to be fired and a internal variable called `_cachedMetaData` to be set to null](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs.html#53ad9885e5a8fc48).

Comment: Yes, it's true. But if an object implements the IDisposable interface, what can I do wrong if I respect the suggested pattern? I prefer to ignore these internals

Comment: So you dispose of every `DataTable` you create, and dispose of every `Task` or `Task<T>` returned from a async method?

Comment: I dispose objects that I don't need anymore

Answer (score 0):

The Problem With Your Code Is That You Have A Command and a Connection But There Is Nothing To Till The Command To Use This Connection Object ... You Can Use The SqlCommand Constructor To Do That

```
scmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO articles(url) VALUES(@url)",scon)
```

Or Use The Connection Property Of The SqlCommand Class Like This

```
scmd.Connection = scon
```

Consider Adding `Using` To Your SQL Connection ... Or Else You Will Have To Manually Close The Connection By Calling `scon.Close();`
if You Didn't Do either Of Those You Will Run Into An Exception If Your Tried To Open The Connection Again While It's Already Open